# Conditional filterBy for v-for loop using Child elements data

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a set of items that I fetch from api. Bellow is example of data I receive from the server.

```
{
    {"name": "example1", "price": 11, "vendor": "vendor_name1" },
    {"name": "example2", "price": 12, "vendor": "vendor_name2" },
    {"name": "example3", "price": 13, "vendor": "vendor_name3" },
}
```

Each of these loop items get assigned with data property `edit: false` which is toggled from false to true based on preference. Is there a way to setup selective "filterBy" that could filter through only the items with edit:false and skip filtering edit:true?

Please see the example:

[Code Pen](http://codepen.io/asolopovas/pen/RajGrB?editors=0010)

Thanks.

Comment: You can get all objects with edit:false with `var noEdit = obj.filter(function(x) { return !x.edit })` then perform whatever calculations you need to on that result.

Comment: The problem is that object is passed to child component. And edit:false is assigned from within. And vue.js does not see that property from the parent scope. It only sees the properties that have been fetched from server.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved it by cloning the item I edit. By Adding $removeBy method and $clone

```
Vue.prototype.$removeBy = ( arr, key, val ) => {
    let index = arr.findIndex( ( e ) => e[ key ] === val );
    if ( index > -1 ) {
        arr.splice( index, 1 );
    }
};

Vue.prototype.$clone = ( obj ) => {
    var target = {};
    for ( var i in obj ) {
        if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
            target[ i ] = obj[ i ];
        }
    }
    return target;
};
```

Working example is here.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/asolopovas/pen/RajGrB?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a custom filter: http://vuejs.org/guide/custom-filter.html

```
Vue.filter('editing',function(obj){
  return !obj.edit;
});
```

Then in your view it would look like:

```
<div v-for="product in products | editing"></div>
```

Comment: It is not going to work, because "edit" property assigned from within child element and parent is not aware of it. Your filter will return nothing as there are no such property in products array as edit. Please see the [CodePen](http://codepen.io/asolopovas/pen/RajGrB?editors=0010) example.

Comment: You need to sync the changes back to the parent then.  Instead of assigning the prop like `:products="products"` do `:products.sync="products"` (or whatever name you have for your property on the child component)

Comment: If you want to use `filterBy` on the array, you would need to make `edit` a property of the product object.  You could do that in the `ready()` function on the `Product` component if you wanted